# Replacing text inside multiple Info.plist files, recursively

Tags: awk, grep

I have a zillions of directories inside a main directory. Each of these directories have multiple levels of subdirectories. Spread among them, there are files called `Info.plist`.

Inside these `Info.plist` files, there are lines line these:

```
<string>/Users/Shared/Library/Mail/V7/74309-67B6-44E3-BD66-9384D1E54398/Junk.mbox</string>
```

these lines, that may be one or multiple per file, may have be different, like

```
<string>/Users/Shared/Library/Mail/V7/74398/Junk.mbox</string>

<string>/Users/Shared/Library/Mail/V7/7-67B8/Sent.mbox</string>

<string>/Users/Shared/Library/Mail/V7/OLD/Old.mbox</string>
```

I am interested in locating these lines inside these `Info.plist` files and change the `Shared` part to `Fireball`.

So, the previous line will become

```
<string>/Users/Fireball/Library/Mail/V7/74398/Junk.mbox</string>

<string>/Users/Fireball/Library/Mail/V7/7-67B8/Sent.mbox</string>

<string>/Users/Fireball/Library/Mail/V7/OLD/Old.mbox</string>
```

Keeping the rest as they are.

So, first I have to scan a directory structure recursive, locate all `Info.plist` files they have, scan inside each `Info.plist` for the `Shared` keyword if they are used in a path and change that to `Fireball`.

How do I do that using some magical unix command?

I am fiddling with this

```
find . -type f -name Info.plist -exec sed 's/Shared/Fireball/g' {} +
```

This almost appears to be working, as it prints to console the correct changes but the files are not altered.

Comment: GNU sed has a `-i` flag to do an inplace edit rather than writing to stdout.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Does your sed implementation have `-i`? Most of the common ones (GNU, BSD, even busybox) have it.

Comment: macOS Catalina, that is problematic in many ways but the solution from @terdon works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `sed` supports the `-i` flag for in-place editing (most of the ones you're likely to encounter in a mainstream operating system do), you can do:

```
find . -type f -name Info.plist -exec sed -i 's/Shared/Fireball/g' {} +
```

If not, you can try `perl` instead:

```
find . -type f -name Info.plist -exec perl -i -pe 's/Shared/Fireball/g' {} +
```

Just make absolutely sure that every instance of the string `Shared` is one you want to replace. It might be safer to use a bit more of the path, just to be on the safe side:

```
find . -type f -name Info.plist -exec sed -i 's|/Users/Shared/Library/|/Users/Fireball/Library|g' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

command

```
find . -type f -iname Info.plist -exec sed "/<string>\/Users\/Shared\/Library\/Mail/s/Shared/Fireball/g" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

output

```
<string>/Users/Fireball/Library/Mail/V7/74398/Junk.mbox</string>

<string>/Users/Fireball/Library/Mail/V7/7-67B8/Sent.mbox</string>

<string>/Users/Fireball/Library/Mail/V7/OLD/Old.mbox</stri
```